# Ionic serve results in a blank page

Tags: ionic-framework

I've recently stumbled upon an annoying problem and can't figure out what could be the cause. I'm working on a ionic hybrid app and since yesterday everything worked fine: I was able to deploy it on my android phone, I could debug it on my browser. Today I open up my project, fire the `ionic serve` and the browser greets me with a blank screen.

I get the address: localhost:8100/, but it really should be localhost:8100/#/app/sessions

The console log report no errors neither the net log.
This is the source code of the index.html page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried to start a new ionic project but the outcome is the same: I get a blank page.
I've set the `ionic serve` address to localhost; I,ve tried to load all angular and ionic module but to no avail. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: type `ionic serve -c` to dump the console logs to see if there is an error, also you could open up the console in the browsers debugger to look for errors

Comment: You dont need to include angular manually if you include ionic.bundle.js.

Comment: Can you please try using the developer tools available in the browser, most probably you will see the error llogs over there due to which the ionic serve shows you the blank page.

Comment: can i see your app.js?

Answer (score 0):

On a closer inspection I found this error (I've skimmed the log):

```
"Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter.controllers due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter.services due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngResource due to:

**[$injector:nomod] Module 'ngResource' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.**
```

I wasn't really sure why but angular coudn't find the ngResource module. A quick check show me spelling wasn't the real problem.

For some reason (on whitch I'm still investigating) publishing the app destroyed angular-resource.js and the resulting .min was lacking the code.
Anyway, when I tried to reload the whole thing, I was loading ngResource version 1.3.15 and angular.js version 1.3.14, making them not working.
So, I was failing Computer Science 101: "always check the versions".

I've set all the version to 1.3.15 and all is working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, we had a very similar problem: `ionic serve -c` had no negative behavior, no error output, simply loaded a blank screen.

The problem in our case was that there was a "!" in the full path of the working directory.

Changing the working directory to a path without a "!" solved this issue.

[Original solution here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/after-serve-no-main-js/73274/16)